# Post on facebook a link to Google Maps static image. Is it legal?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a web application of routes, when a user uploads a route, I want the route is published on Facebook as a static image of Google maps. This publication is a link to a page that has a map of Google maps.

I want to know whether the terms of use of Google are met, to take a picture of Google and give to Facebook.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Comment: I thought it was the right place. Where I can ask the question?

Comment: If you are unsure about the Terms of Use of Google, the only valid way will be asking a Google representative directly rather than relying on some anonymous Q&A site response. What if I claimed you're okay doing it and Google sent their lawyers to sue the bejeezus out of you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static Maps must always be loaded directly from the original google-address.

When "give to Facebook" means that the image will be uploaded to another server(e.g. facebook), and in the future will be loaded from this server: **it's not permitted**